# Need to multiply each column by the top cell in that column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF:

```
Score1 Score2 Score3
1      3      4
0      0      0
2      3      5
1      6      2
```

And I want to multiply each column by the top of that columns cell.  So the output would be :

```
Score1 Score2 Score3
1      3      4
0      0      0
2      9     20
1     18      8
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `df.update`

```
df.update(df.iloc[0] * df.iloc[1:])
print(df)

# Output:
   Score1  Score2  Score3
0     1.0     3.0     4.0
1     0.0     0.0     0.0
2     2.0     9.0    20.0
3     1.0    18.0     8.0
```

Or `combine_first`:

```
df = df.iloc[0].mul(df.iloc[1:]).combine_first(df)
print(df)

# Output:
   Score1  Score2  Score3
0       1       3       4
1       0       0       0
2       2       9      20
3       1      18       8
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also prevent loss of dtypes/values by using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) on both sides of assignment. This removes the need to merge back to fill created `NaN` values:

```
df.iloc[1:, :] = df.iloc[1:, :] * df.iloc[0, :]
```

Or with assignment by multiplication:

```
df.iloc[1:, :] *= df.iloc[0, :]
```

Or with explicit axis alignment via [`DataFrame.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
df.iloc[1:, :] = df.iloc[1:, :].mul(df.iloc[0, :], axis=1)
```

All options produce `df`:

```
   Score1  Score2  Score3
0       1       3       4
1       0       0       0
2       2       9      20
3       1      18       8
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Score1': [1, 0, 2, 1], 'Score2': [3, 0, 3, 6], 'Score3': [4, 0, 5, 2]
})
```

Comment: You can simply do `df.iloc[1:] *= df.iloc[0]`. But I agree this is the best way!

Comment: Nice. Thank you! I do prefer the verbose but that does totally work here as well.

Comment: Fair enough! explicit is better than implicit ;)

Comment: [That's what the manual says at least](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#toc-entry-2) :-)